# Fetching Nhibernate Lazy data inside mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, session

I want to fetch lazy data inside mvc view.
So I have created an `ActionFilterAttribute` as you can see bellow.
But for some reason, the session close before `OnActionExecuted`.
Any Idea why?
Tx

```
public class DatabaseTransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            DatabaseConnector.GetTransaction();
        }



        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if(DatabaseConnector.GetCurrentSession().IsActive())
            {
                if(filterContext.Exception == null)
                {
                    DatabaseConnector.GetCurrentSession().Commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    DatabaseConnector.GetCurrentSession().MarkForRollBack();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the View is evaluated **after** the OnActionExecuted method.

If you *really* want to lazy-load data inside the view (it's not recommended as it opens you up to N+1 errors), you will want to commit your transaction in the OnResultExecuted method instead.

Please consider carefully before doing this - your original code was preferred.

For example

```
public class DatabaseTransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        DatabaseConnector.GetTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if(DatabaseConnector.GetCurrentSession().IsActive())
        {
            if(filterContext.Exception == null)
            {
                DatabaseConnector.GetCurrentSession().Commit();
            }
            else
            {
                DatabaseConnector.GetCurrentSession().MarkForRollBack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```